# background-image in CSS not working on Samsung TV SDK 2011 model/emulator

Tags: css, image, sdk, television

I am making an app on a Samsung TV SDK and I am tryiing to display an image using background-image on CSS but it's not being honored on 2011 model/emulator.  I know I can use  on html but I need to put it on my js file. How can I do that? Any alternate solutions? Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue and to share the answer... in able to use image on js file use this:

```
var image_name = "image.png";
$('#Sceneid').html('<img src="' + image_name + '"/>');
```

That's it! HTML 5 won't work on 2011 models.